# Excel interop range find entire cell contents

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Is there any way to set this excel flag (match entire cell contents) on by code?
Currently i'm using the following, but it gaves me only partial match
eg. lookin value is 1520 and it finds 651520
or just use in case the findnext method for it?

```
currentFind = insta.Find(line, Missing.Value, XlFindLookIn.xlValues, XlLookAt.xlPart, XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from `XlLookAt.xlPart` to `XlLookAt.xlWhole`.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx